# Google Map does not show up in Microsoft Excel Data Entry Form

Tags: excel, vba, button, dynamicform

I have created a dynamic data entry form in Excel with two fields, latitude & Longitude while double-clicking on the row of Lat & Long in the database it displays the location of the lat and long in google map in the browser, however;

I am trying to get the location map opened in the form, if the user selects a row (Land&Long) and click on the Map Button, it should display the location of the selected Lat and Long in the form (frmMap). The problem is that it does not work with the form inside the Dataentry form, here is the code.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code *as text*, not a screenshot.

Comment: You can use the WebBrowser control's methods to navigate to the page directly instead of using FollowHyperlink

Comment: Thanks, Tim it worked but I get an error the screenshot is posted above, any suggestion.